# Updating Rails record with self-join association doesn't update self join column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, self-join

For my `Employee` class, I have the following self-joinig associations:

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :replaces_employee, class_name: "Employee", optional: true

  has_one :replaced_by_employee,
    class_name: 'Employee',
    foreign_key: 'replaces_employee_id'
end
```

And my `employees` DB table has the column `replaces_employee_id`.

In my app, if an employee gets a new role, the following occurs:

1. Current employee record is cloned.
2. `<current record's>.replaces_employee` = cloned record
3. Cloned record is saved.
4. Current employee record is saved to persist other data attributes (i.e. name change).  During this save, Rails auto-magically updated the current record's `replaces_employee_id` column with the cloned record ID.

Yep, that magic was great and worked in my old Rails 4.2 app.  Unfortunately this isn't working for my Rails 7.0 app.  I've tried updating the `belongs_to` association with an explicit foreign key to no avail.  Please note for existing DB records that do have `replaces_employee_id` populated, I have access to the associated ARs (i.e. `Employee.find(1).replaces_employee` works).

Any ideas why this isn't working for Rails 7?  Was there some configuration on the 4.2 side that I'm missing?

Comment: can you show what's not working? `current = Employee.create!; current.replaces_employee = current.dup; current.save!; Employee.all.as_json #=> [{"id"=>1, "replaces_employee_id"=>2}, {"id"=>2, "replaces_employee_id"=>nil}]`

Comment: Can you share database migration?

Comment: @titan2gman - My `employees` DB table was created YEARS ago.  After that, the `replaces_employee` column was added using this statement in a DB migration --> `add_column :employees, :replaces_employee_id, :integer`.  As you can see, there's no reference.  In my DB this column is simply an `integer`; no foreign key reference.

Comment: @Alex - In my old, Rails 4.2 code I have (distilled of course); `temp_clone = create_deep_clone; self.replaces_employee = temp_clone; temp_clone.update_attributes!(bla bla bla); self.save`.  I use `deep_cloneable` within `#create_deep_clone`. The `update_attributes!` call saves the `replaces_employee` record. When I call `self.save`, I can see in the log `UPDATE "employees" SET "<additional updates>", "replaces_employee_id"`. So all looks good.

Comment: @Alex - In my new code, Rails 7.2,I follow the same steps, but the log excludes `replaces_employee_id` and simply updates all other attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Besides that there is no `update_attributes!` method in *rails 7*, everything seem to work:

```rb
# app/models/employee.rb

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :replaces_employee, class_name: "Employee", optional: true
  has_one :replaced_by_employee, class_name: "Employee", foreign_key: "replaces_employee_id"

  def replace
    # how deep is deep clone? did you check for validation errors?
    other = deep_clone
    other.attributes = {name: "copy of #{name}"}
    # call `save!` or `update!` to raise validation errors
    # when you call `save` or `update` you need to check for `errors`
    #  employee.save
    #  employee.errors #=> ???
    update!({name: "new name",
             replaces_employee: other})
  end
end
```

```rb
>> Employee.create!
=> #<Employee:0x00007eff8c5cc5a0 id: 1, name: nil, replaces_employee_id: nil>
>> Employee.first.replace
=> true
>> Employee.all
=>
[#<Employee:0x00007eff7e4e08c0 id: 1, name: "replaced name", replaces_employee_id: 2>,
 #<Employee:0x00007eff7e4e0780 id: 2, name: "copy of ", replaces_employee_id: nil>]

>> 3.times { Employee.first.replace }
=> 3
# i just dont' know if that's how you expect this to work
>> Employee.all
=> 
[#<Employee:0x00007eff8c11ce60 id: 1, name: "new name", replaces_employee_id: 5>,
 #<Employee:0x00007eff8c11cd20 id: 2, name: "copy of ", replaces_employee_id: nil>,
 #<Employee:0x00007eff8c11cbe0 id: 3, name: "copy of new name", replaces_employee_id: 2>,
 #<Employee:0x00007eff8c11caa0 id: 4, name: "copy of new name", replaces_employee_id: 3>,
 #<Employee:0x00007eff8c11c960 id: 5, name: "copy of new name", replaces_employee_id: 4>]
```